# DLL load failed in xlwings UDF

Tags: udf, xlwings, pyd

I am trying to import a user-defined function (UDF, hereafter) through `xlwings` add-in. That UDF is using a DLL (in the form of `.pyd`). When I try to import the UDF into excel through `xlwings` add-in, I am facing a run-time error.
The below is the Visual Basic Error message:

> -2147467259(80004005) run-time error
>   ImportError : DLL load failed
>   import BS1DCallPut
>   ... File "", line 222, in  -call_with_frames_removed

Actually the error is occurring in the part of importing the DLL.(`BS1DCallPut.pyd` is the name of the DLL)

There's no problem with that DLL elsewhere. For example, I can perfectly import that DLL in a `Jupyter` notebook and can do some calculations with it, no problem.